# Cannot reference algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

For some reason referencing an algorithm displays always 0 instead of actual number of the algorithm. References work, I can click on it and it will move me to the algorithm.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
It doesn't work \ref{alg1} \ref{alg2}.

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Algorithm 1}
    \begin{algorithmic}[ht]
    \label{alg1}
        \State it's a test
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\newpage

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Algorithm 2}
    \begin{algorithmic}[ht]
    \label{alg2}
        \State it's a test
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\label` goes directly after `\caption`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
It doesn't work \ref{alg1} \ref{alg2}.

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Algorithm 1}
    \label{alg1}
    \begin{algorithmic}[ht]
        \State it's a test
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\newpage

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Algorithm 2}
    \label{alg2}
    \begin{algorithmic}[ht]
        \State it's a test
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Place the `\label` immediately after `\caption{…}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\algorithmautorefname}{Algorithm}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
It does work Algorithm~\ref{alg1} and \autoref{alg2}.

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Algorithm 1}
    \label{alg1}
    \begin{algorithmic}[ht]
        \State it's a test
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\newpage

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Algorithm 2}
    \label{alg2}
    \begin{algorithmic}[ht]
        \State it's a test
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

In the example I've also shown, how to use `\autoref` with algorithm reference.

[image]